# How do i only paste rotation to a bone

Tags: bones

Im making a animation and i woud like to paste the rotation of a bone from one keyframe to another. But the problem is that i also paste the location of it. I tried locking the transform but it still didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select only the keyframes you want to copy with **B** in the Dope Sheet and copy/paste them between frames:

[image: Copying bone rotation]

Answer (score 0):

If we assume you are not using automatic keyframe insertion, you can copy keyframe and paste as stated in your question.

Next only insert keyframe rotation. The menu <kbd>i</kbd> show choices for selective keyframe insertion. You can move the frame cursor back and forth to confirm you have only set a keyframe for rotation, not location.

[image]